# Log statement doesnot show when asynctask is waiting

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an async task in which in the dobackground it logs a statement and wait for some interrupt. My problem is that the debug statement does not show although I know the code is being excuted!!! Why and how can  I fix that?

```
 private class GameAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Object, Boolean> {




        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("GameMonitor", "onPreExecute"); //this one shows

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


                while(true){

                          Log.d("GameMonitor", "AyncTask start"); // does not show
                    ...// some variable are set and i know they are being set
                          wait(); 
                 }
            }
}
```

My expectation is something around " thread is till processing and by waiting the debug statement is blocked". However it is debug , shouldnt be happening before the wait?

Comment: I agree that the wait() might be causing the log line not to be output. As an experiment, try temporarily putting a short sleep between the log() and the wait() to see what happens.

Comment: Wouldn't sleep hog the cpu too? I will try

Comment: @scottt I tried it , no luck :(

Comment: In that case, it appears that something else is causing the issue. If you're sure the task is getting started and are successfully getting other Log messages, just not this one, then I'm stumped too.

Comment: By the way, a common convention for log messages is to define a string constant named TAG at the start of each class and use that for the first argument to the Log statement. It makes Log statements a bit shorter and avoids problems with typos.